# Can I use SUMIF with OFFSET to get my totals?

Tags: excel-formula

Hi so I have the data at follows:

1. Alex 300 400
2. Sarah 200 400
3. Total 500 800
4. John 700 300
5. Alex 200 300
6. Total 900 600

I am thinking I need to search the text total and sum the cell on the right of it. But I only want the totals. This list may be added to.
Additionally I want to grab the second column as well as a separate formula hence why I’m thinking using offset.

**Added Info:**

From the below example i may have multiple Job Blocks with a Total field.
What i wish to achieve is search all cells in Column A for text "Total", then SUM all green values in Column B. Separately i wish to also do the same with Blue fields in Column C using Total as an anchor point.

I hope this clarifies this a little.

[image: Example of sheet]

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. Why are you wanting to return the Total if you already have the total? Can you show us the expected output with your example?

Comment: I will add the example when I arrive home, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild I have added my example sheet hopefully this makes a little more sense.

Comment: Ah, so there are multiple "Total"s. Okay see my edits below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `OFFSET`. Just use `SUMIF`.

For example, if you have the resulting formulas below your data, just use:

`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$100, "Total", B$1:B$100)` and drag to the right.

If you have the newest version of Excel, you can also use `FILTER` like

`=SUM(FILTER($B1:B$100, $A$1:$A$100="Total"))`

If you want the results stored in a way that isn't right below the data, and want to drag the data, I prefer `INDIRECT`.
`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$100, "Total", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1),COLUMN(B1))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(B100), COLUMN(B100))))`

Comment: I am not familiar with unique in practice how does it relate to the second formula? Unique seems to duplicate the column is there any method without needing to duplicate?

Comment: Well if you only want the totals for each individual, you only want to ```SUMIF``` once on each individual. So ```UNIQUE``` will get you that list of unique names, then you can use ```SUMIF``` on each name and drag down

Comment: I’m this case I want to target the Total row instead of having to sum individually. Total text will always be the same, using offset seems to only capture one and I want to sum all total fields in the column.

Comment: Can this be fine tuned let’s say first column numbers is A and second is B, I want to sum all totals of A into a single cell, then all total of B in another cell. Formula fields will not be next to each other due to how the report is structured. So a formula of each condition may be needed. Keeping in mind that additional total cells would be added. Thank you for helping me :)